# gnu makefile for C embedded

Tags: c, makefile

I am having a problem with my Makefile. I want to have following targets. compile, link, hex, flash. I want the Makefile to be in the root directory and compile all source files that are in ./src
directory. The resulting object and hex file should be in ./build. Here is my code so far:

```
CC := avr-gcc
MCU := atmega328p
SRC := ./src
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)                     # finds all .c files in the directory
OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC)%.c, $(SRC)%.o, $(SRCS))  # change list of source files into list of object files replacing suffix .c with .o

CFLAGS := -o tmpfile -mmcu=$(MCU) -Os -D F_CPU=16E6 -D DEBUG_MODE=0 -D COUNTDOWN_MODE=1 \
         -D LAPCOUNTER_MODE=1 -D LAPS=3 -Wall;

all: compile link hex flash

compile: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS)

link:


hex:
    avr-objcopy -O ihex tmpfile tmpfile.hex


flash:
    avrdude -c arduino -p atmega328p -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:tmpfile.hex
```

It gives to following error that I dont understand how to fix:

```
avr-gcc: fatal error: no input files
/bin/sh: 1: -c: not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'src/iesmotors.o' failed
make: *** [src/iesmotors.o] Error 127
```

I also dont understand how I can compile and link seperately.

Comment: I think the semicolon at the end of `CFLAGS` is the source of the problem. What did you intend it to do? What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your shell is `sh` and not `bash`, and it should be bash as you see in this line

```
/bin/sh: 1: -c: not found
```

the error says that `-c` is not found, while `-c` flag is part of the bash, I think you have to change the shell to the bash.

you can try this command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

to change the current shell to the bash.

Comment: is there a way to achieve what I want with shell?

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder yes, you can do it but with ```bash``` in the shell, not ```sh```! you should understand the difference between using ```sh``` and ```bash```, then you can use bash commands in the makefile.

Comment: yeah I have no idea what the difference is.